# System halt in linux

Tags: c, linux, kernel

I was looking at reboot.c in the Linux kernel.

http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/kernel/reboot.c

There is a call to kernel_halt it says that this function will
Shutdown everything and perform a clean system halt.
What does a clean system halt mean?
Can any one explain what this halt actually does?
I am also wondering about syscore what kind of operations are considered as syscore operation?

```
  0 void kernel_halt(void)
    161 {
    162         kernel_shutdown_prepare(SYSTEM_HALT);
    163         migrate_to_reboot_cpu();
    164         syscore_shutdown();
    165         pr_emerg("System halted\n");
    166         kmsg_dump(KMSG_DUMP_HALT);
    167         machine_halt();
    168 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`syscore_shutdown()` will check all registered syscore operations ([drivers/base/syscore.c](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/base/syscore.c?v=3.13#L110)"*Execute all the registered system core shutdown callbacks.*") for non-NULL operation `shutdown` and will execute them. Syscore operations are registered using [`register_syscore_ops`](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/ident?i=register_syscore_ops), and most drivers register only `resume` and `suspend` fields of syscore_ops.

There is partial list of syscore registrations with `shutdown` field as of linux kernel version 3.13 for x86/x86_64:

1) [`arch/x86/kernel/i8259.c`](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/x86/kernel/i8259.c?v=3.13#L269): [`i8259A_shutdown`](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/x86/kernel/i8259.c#L259)

```
261         /* Put the i8259A into a quiescent state that
262          * the kernel initialization code can get it
263          * out of.
264          */
265         outb(0xff, PIC_MASTER_IMR);     /* mask all of 8259A-1 */
266         outb(0xff, PIC_SLAVE_IMR);      /* mask all of 8259A-2 */
```

2) [`arch/x86/kernel/cpu/mcheck/mce.c`](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/x86/kernel/cpu/mcheck/mce.c?v=3.13#L2063), `mce_syscore_shutdown` which calls  [`mce_disable_error_reporting`](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/x86/kernel/cpu/mcheck/mce.c?v=3.13#L2025)

```
2026  * Disable machine checks on suspend and shutdown. We can't really handle
2027  * them later.
 ....
2037                         wrmsrl(MSR_IA32_MCx_CTL(i), 0);
```

3) [kernel/irq/generic-chip.c](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/kernel/irq/generic-chip.c?v=3.13#L580) [`irq_gc_shutdown`](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/kernel/irq/generic-chip.c?v=3.13#L564): for each element in `gc_list`, try to run `ct->chip.irq_pm_shutdown(data);`; the "*@irq_pm_shutdown:    function called from core code on shutdown once per chip*" ([description](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/irq.h?v=3.13#L280))

4) [drivers/leds/trigger/ledtrig-cpu.c](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/leds/trigger/ledtrig-cpu.c?v=3.13#L89):

```
 84 static void ledtrig_cpu_syscore_shutdown(void)
 85 {
 86         ledtrig_cpu(CPU_LED_HALTED);
 87 }
...
 61         case CPU_LED_HALTED:
 62                 /* Will turn the LED off */
 63                 led_trigger_event(trig->_trig, LED_OFF);
```

> What does a clean system halt mean?

Unmount cleanly everything, switch off all hardware.

> I am also wondering about syscore what kind of operations are considered as syscore operation?

Syscore is used to register some functions to work at suspend/restore and shutdown. Very small number of drivers registers syscore shutdown virtual functions, for example: turning PC case LEDs ([not keyboard's leds](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/leds/leds-class.txt) off, disabling interrupts, disabling machine checks (I think like ECC error, because there will be nobody to report them to system log), ...

> Can any one explain what this halt actually does?

This halt: switches to the 0 CPU core, because only it can do reboot or shutdown, runs all registered pre-shutdown handlers, then prints "System halted" and  and asks hardware to do actual poweroff.

```
162         kernel_shutdown_prepare(SYSTEM_HALT);
163         migrate_to_reboot_cpu();
164         syscore_shutdown();
165         pr_emerg("System halted\n");
166         kmsg_dump(KMSG_DUMP_HALT);
167         machine_halt();
```